# Potential for data corruption in rsync through daemon and cron job between two servers both ways

Tags: cron, rsync, synchronization, corruption

I have set up two servers to synchronise using `rsync` daemons and `cron` job every 5 minutes.

- Server A has a daemon that makes a folder available via alias.
- Server B has a daemon that makes a folder (same path) available via alias.
- Server A has a `cron` job that syncs the folder (same path) to server A's daemon alias.
- Server B has a `cron` job that syncs the folder (same path) to server A's daemon alias.
- The `rsync` command is given the parameters `-urtzv`.
- The server clocks are synchronized.
- The `cron` job runs every 5 minutes (at the 5 minute tick on clock face), so both servers would execute at the same time (approximately).

Are there any potential problems in doing this? Specifically:

- Would there be data corruption because both servers are executing `rsync` at the same time? Or do the daemons intelligently handle conflicts?
- Would there be data corruption if (for example) server A is transferring to server B for more than 5 minutes (in a single `rsync` run), but then server B executes `rsync` the other way about 5 minutes after the long-running `rsync` on server A was started?
- In last case, would there be data corruption if, in addition to that, another process on server A was also writing into the file for more than 5 minutes?

I read that running `rsync` twice in parallel (on same server and source/destination) should be safe in terms of data integrity, though it might degrade performance. I also learnt that `rsync` stores the incoming data in temporary files and only moves them into the permanent files once transfer is complete. But I'm unsure of the behavior when `rsync` is setup on two servers to sync both ways at the same time.

*If this is better asked in Server Fault, please let me know.*

Comment: Why do you set up rsync on both for the same folder?! Usually you set it up on one server and say to synchronize both computers. Then the rsync system does it right...

Comment: So there is potential for data corruption in my current setup? I should probably change it, but is it known to be unsafe?

Comment: I'd be worried about rsync's temporary files getting synced back and forth, mostly. (And while we're on unwanted advice ;), [lsyncd](https://axkibe.github.io/lsyncd/) may be interesting to do, it will use inotify instead of a frequent cronjob, that might make often-changing files safer to sync.)

Comment: I think the safest is to do the `rsync` both ways from one of the computers. Run a first time from A to B, then next from B to A. If you do not use the `--delete`, I do not think it will be much of a problem that way. If files can get deleted... That's more complicated!

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz lsyncd is interesting, but I cannot install software in the servers (not without cutting through a lot of red tape, anyway). For this reason, I also cannot use Unison, a two-way sync tool. I'm limited to built-in software or those already installed.

Comment: @AlexisWilke not using `--delete` My arguments are `-urtz --port` only. Yes I decided to change to that model where only one server runs a daemon, and the other server pushes and pulls the new files. I also think it is safer. However, the question is whether the danger in running daemons in both servers and pushing both ways at the same time is **real or imaginary**.

Comment: This seems a job for DRDB...your setup is too consulted for my taste.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro distributed replicated block device? And what do you mean by "too consulted"?

Comment: Dictionaries playing a joke...convoluted.